# MOSS 2007 recovery using Data Protection Manager

Tags: backup, sharepoint, scdpm

I'm trying to recover a part of SharePoint document library to a network folder. Sharepoint server already has a DPM agent and everything is backed up regularly. When I start recovery wizard in DPM,in the "recovery options" window of the System Center Data Protection Manager,"Export selected items to a network folder" option is grayed out. Is it not possible for SharePoint or is it any missing settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with SharePoint - you can only restore back to a SharePoint farm/site/server

Comment: Best practice with DPM is to have a "restore farm" that you use to restore redirected data to. This can be a VM which is brought online only for restores (and updates, so it's the same version as the production farm).

Comment: I should add that it's also sort of best practice to have a restore farm regardless of the backup solution you use because of the issues involved in restoring over live data.

Answer (score 0):

DPM doesnt have an option to recover to a particular folder. This is by design to protect the securty related information for the document. You can however create a temporary site in your farm and recover the document there. Once recovered, you can download it to the required network folder.